# Access permissions for directory in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a programm which creates log files in web-server directory (/var/www/log). Every day it generates one new log file. I've set access permissions for this directory to 777

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/log
```

But when system generates log file for new day, it doesn't have access permissions 777. I have to do it manually again. How can I correctly set permissions for directory? All files in this directory must have 777 automatically.

Comment: Why would a log directory ever need `god mode`?

Comment: Can you have to logs go elsewhere?  Like the home directory?

Comment: Why give log files execute permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access permissions on a directory do not determine the access permissions for a file in that directory in Linux; they are not inherited.

Either change the umask(2) of the program that writes the logfiles, or change the settings of the program that rotates the logfiles.